# My table is lock to see the records, and I can't delete my trigger

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-delete, ddl

I created a trigger that create duplicates and stored procedure to send the details to my email, it works fine. After I executed it, and I tried to look the table where I created the trigger takes so long and I can't see my record. And I tried to delete the trigger and it doesn't let. I said there is some lock/bloc but I'm not familiar with those commands. In the Activity Monitor said that it is SUSPENDED

---

Drop failed for Trigger 'AfterDeletedTrigger'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table actually is locked, running `select * from sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` should help you identify if there is actually any locking or not. 
Also here is a link that could potentially help you resolve you issue as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2016/aa337412(v=sql.130)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank You Angesehen, actually I did was I ran the query and then opened the Activity Monitor. I saw my blocking_id and my status (SUSPENDED) you can kill it but it wasn't working. So, I wrote a query "KILL (BLOCKING_ID)" and the query ran and I could delete the trigger

Comment: @GabrielMolina glad that you got it fixed!